# Image gallery sending position url and display Android

Tags: android, android-intent, image-gallery

I am sending a selected image from image gallery to NextImage.java activity using intent.  I want to send the selected position of the image and the arrays of image to next activity. am getting confused with the intent part can someone help please

code to send clicked item and urls to nextImage Activity.

public void showGallery(){

```
   String[]imageUrls= new String[PostDetails.size()];

       for (int index=0;index<imageUrls.length;index++){
           imageUrls[index]=PostDetails.get(index).getImag();
    }

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(3))
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();


    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.img_gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));


    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> gallery, View view, int position, long id) {



              Intent galleryIntent  = new Intent(ImageGalleryActivity.this, MyNextImage.class);

              galleryIntent.putExtra(imageUrls, position);
              startActivity(galleryIntent);

          }
```

}

My next image class is as follows.

public class NextImage extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {

```
private ViewPager pager;
String[] imageUrls;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
String images;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.view_flipper_item);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(images);
    int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(position, 0);
```